# How can I get Technical Names of my Fields Using COPY Command

Tags: postgresql, csv

I wrote my code, I am getting all the data from my Postgres Database but fields technical names stored in my database are not coming under my xlsx file??
Below is my code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=cush2 user=tryton50 password=admin host=localhost")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM cushing_syndrome) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ','"
with open("/home/cf/Desktop/result_1.xlsx", "w") as file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

Comment: Use "CSV HEADER" instead of "CSV"

Comment: And you are creating a *.csv file not a *.xlsx file.

Comment: @Hambone it is working now!!!

Comment: But one2many data is not coming?? How can i get one2many data in a single row. Any reference to this issue will be highly grateful!!!